# ColorPicker in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

```
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;

var myColorPicker:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
myColorPicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeHandler);
myColorPicker.move(10, 10);
addChild(myColorPicker);

function changeHandler(event:ColorPickerEvent) {
    trace("color changed:", event.color, "(#" + event.target.hexValue + ")");
 trace(myColorPicker.hexValue);
}
```

I need the value of `event.target.hexValue` outside of the function. I'm using actions in Flash CS5.

Comment: use [selectedColor](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html#selectedColor) property

Comment: why don't you store the required value in a global variable that can be accessed outside the changeHandler function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var borderColor:uint = 0x000000;

var myColorPicker:ColorPicker = new ColorPicker();
myColorPicker.editable = true;
myColorPicker.move(10, 10);
addChild(myColorPicker);

myColorPicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, changeHandler);

function changeHandler (event:ColorPickerEvent):void {
    var newuint = uint("0x"+event.target.hexValue);
    borderColor = newuint;
    graphics.lineStyle(2,borderColor,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: If you're looking for the value of selected color as uint, you can directly use the [selectedColor](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/ColorPicker.html#selectedColor) property of ColorPicker `event.target.selectedColor` or [color](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/events/ColorPickerEvent.html#color) property of the ColorPickerEvent `event.color`

---

Unless you have multiple color pickers that use same change handler, the value of `event.target`, (or `event.currentTarget` to be precise), is the same as `myColorPicker` that can be accessed from outside the function without any problem. Hence, you can use `myColorPicker.hexValue` outside the function. If the code you want to access this doesn't have access to `myColorPicker`, you can pass the value of `myColorPicker.hexValue` to that function as a parameter.

<sup>If this is not what you wanted, please clarify the question.</sup>

Comment: This is what I want to do: I want the value of `myColorPicker.hexValue` into something like this. `graphics.Linestyle(2, myColorPicker.hexVale/someVariableName, 1)`

Comment: Where do you want to do this - did you get any error when you tried this?

Comment: yeah, but i solved the problem now. The code is definitely not clean and easily readable, but it is good enough for now.